# Process Communication via unnamed pipes

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, file-handling

What I am trying to do is read a file in child process and pass it to parent via a pipe. where it is modified and stored in another array and passed via another pipe to child where it shall be stored in an updated file. All seems well until it is modified and I have a modified string in parent but I am unable to pass it back to child. Following is the code. I cannot find the problem here can someone point it out for me

````
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{int fd1[2];
      int fd2[2];
      int fdo,fdi;
      long int size=findSize(argv[1]);
      if(pipe(fd1)==-1)
      {write(1,"Error",5);
      return 2;}
      if(pipe(fd2)==-1)
      {write(1,"Error",5);
      return 1;}
      fdi=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
      fdo=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY);
      int e=fork();
    //_______________________________________________________
      if(e==0)
      {//close(fd1[0]);
      //close(fd2[1]);
      char * message;
      char * message2;
      message=malloc(size);
      message2=malloc(size);
      if(fdi!=-1)
    {
    if(read(fdi,message,size)==-1)
    {
    write(1,"Error",5);
    return 0;
    }}
     //printf("%s",message);
     if(write(fd1[1],&message,size)==-1)
     printf("error agya paiin\n");
     //wait(NULL);
     read(fd2[0],&message2,size);
     printf("__________________________________________\n %s",message2);
     if(fdo!=-1)
    {
    if(write(fdo,message2,size)==-1)
    {
    write(1,"Error",5);
    return 0;
    }}
     close(fd1[1]);
      close(fd2[0]);
     }
     //_______________________________________________
      if(e>0)
      {
      close(fd1[1]);
      close(fd2[0]);
      char * message;
      char * message2;
      message=malloc(size);
      message2=malloc(size);
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
      message2[i]=32;
      }
      if(read(fd1[0],&message,size)==-1)
      printf("error\n");
int j=0;
         for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
         if((message[i]<48) || (message[i]>57))
         {
         message2[j]=message[i];
         if((message[i]>64) && (message[i]<91))
         {
         message2[j]+=32;
         }
         else if((message[i]>96) && (message[i]<123))
         {
         message2[j]-=32;
         }
         j++;
         }
         }
         message2[j]=0;
    if(write(fd2[1],&message2,size)==-1)
      {printf("could not pass\n");
      return 1;}
      close(fd1[0]); 
      close(fd2[1]);
      }
return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` and `write` calls that you are making on the pipe are incorrect. You are passing a pointer to the buffer instead of the buffer itself. For instance, the call:

```
if(write(fd1[1],&message,size)==-1)
```

should be:

```
if(write(fd1[1],message,size)==-1)
```

Same with all other calls to the pipes.

You can think about reading and writing to the pipe just as if you were reading and writing to a file (these operations are correct in your code, that's why I say it).